# Excel pivot table stacking fields

Tags: excel, pivot-table

(Excel 2010) I have a range with multiple column in it and want to do something like this :

Data : 
Food type  - Food item - Date       - Price
Vegetables - Tomatoes  - 2016-01-01 - 5$
Vegetables - Tomatoes  - 2016-01-02 - 7$
Vegetables - cucumber  - 2016-01-01 - 6$
Vegetables - cucumber  - 2016-01-02 - 8$
Fruits     - Apple     - 2016-01-01 - 5$
Meat       - Beef      - 2016-01-01 - 10$

The result I want : 
Fields - Avg(Price)
Tomatoes   - 6$
Cucumber   - 7$
Apple      - 5$
Beef       - 10$
Vegetables - 6.5$
Fruits     - 5$
Meat       - 10$

So I want to stack the fields one over the other and not in a hierarchy like this

Vegetables
 - Tomatoes
 - Cucumber
Fruits
 
 - Apple
Meat 
 - Beef

Any Idea on how I could do this without manipulating the data ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Copy the `Price` column into a column on its immediate right. Create a PivotTable from multiple consolidation ranges (eg as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20543651/1505120) as far as #4) with one range starting `Food Type` and ending at the left-hand `Price` column adding a second starting at `Food item` and ending at the right-hand `Price` column. Set the VALUES area to be Average of Value, uncheck *Show grand totals for rows* and *Show grand totals for columns* if necessary, hide the `Date` and `Food item` columns, order and format to suit.

[image: SO38076959 example]